# Is it worth "piling in more insulation"?

Tags: insulation, attic

In one area the laughable insulation in my attic looks like this:

[image]

purely as a stopgap measure: is it worth simply ...

1. get the keys to my kid's minivan and drive to Lowe's on the corner and get a sack or two of loose insulation
2. cut the sack open and pile more loose insulation on top of the photographed area

Is it even worth the ten minutes / ten bucks to do this?

Would it perhaps **slightly cool the room underneath the problem area**??

Or is it really pointless on such a poorly insulated setup?

Comment: Honest, my third and final Newb Insulation question

Comment: How deep is the insulation there?

Comment: @fixer1234, it's scattered, 2" to 4" at best!

Comment: I would bring it up to the level it is everywhere else.  Insulation is cheap and pays for itself.  No way to predict what effect it will have on how much cooler the room underneath it will feel.  A lot of that depends on the general air circulation of your HVAC.  That could carry away the excess heat, but you would still be paying for it in your utility bill.

Comment: FYI I did throw in a few bags - we'll see !

Comment: I've never seen a poorly insulated attic that didn't have other problems too. I suggest you vacuum it out, check for any infestation, verify ventilation, then have new stuff blown in

Comment: yeah it's a great point @Matthew - good one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, it's a good idea to have more insulation. Our contractor recently performed some remodeling and suggested to re-insulate our entire house while insulating the remodeled section. The existing insulation had been trampled, pushed and bunched up all over the place. The new, blown in stuff must be eight to ten inches deep over all the old stuff.

If nothing else, the house is more uniform in temperature, but that might have also been the result of opening up the new room to normal air movement.

You can use an IR thermometer on the old insulation area and take a reading when the A/C is running, to have an idea how much cold is seeping upward. Alternatively, read the ceiling temperature under the sparse locations, then compare those same readings after you apply your insulation.

I have a cheap HF IR thermometer. It matters not how accurate it is, as you're looking for differential readings. It's also fun to do this sort of test with an IR camera on an iPhone or similar.

Comment: it's a great idea to read "the top of the insulation". I'll get right on it.  I rushed to the store and bought a IR thermometer gun as soon as I became interested in this topic today :)